# Re-adding .efi file to uefi boot

Tags: linux, windows, boot, multi-boot, uefi

After upgrading to windows 11 my Kali Linux entry disappeared from the Boot menu. When I  hit <kbd>F9</kbd> (select boot device) I can select windows, or I can browse the efi partition and select the `grubx64.efi` file which boots Kali linux.

How do I re-add Kali to the UEFI list when I hit <kbd>F9</kbd> ?

Answer (score 0):

First, boot into linux.

Make sure that you have `efibootmgr` installed.

## Ensure that the path to the .efi file is correct.

1. Run `sudo fdisk -l` and look for the partition of Type `EFI System`. (`/dev/sda2` in my case)
2. Mount the partition to /mnt `sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt`
3. Browse the file system and ensure the path of the file (`EFI/kali/grubx64.efi` in my case)

## Verify the linux partition

Refer to the `sudo fdisk -l` and find the partition that contains your Linux installation (`/dev/sda6` in my case)

## Create the new UEFI menu item

Using the values found previously, execute the following command:
`sudo efibootmgr --create --disk=/dev/sda --part=6 --label="Kali" --loader='EFI\kali\grubx64.efi'`